# Realm accessed from incorrect thread with unmanaged objects

Tags: swift, realm

The realm documentation says T(value: Any) creates an unmanaged object, and such objects don't have issues being handled in different threads, what's going on here?

```
func getOne<T : Object>(type : T.Type) -> Promise<T> {
        return Promise { seal in
            self.operatingQueue.async {
                autoreleasepool {
                    if let realm = self.openRealm() {

                        let results = realm.objects(T.self)

                        if let first = results.first {
                            let unmanaged : T = T(value: first, schema : .partialPrivateShared())
                            seal.fulfill(unmanaged)
                        }

                    } else {
                        seal.reject(PersistanceError.couldNotOpenDatabase)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This code crashes with:

```
2019-11-13 20:08:51.259420-0500 CommonStock[6395:131786] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0 CoreFoundation 0x00007fff23baa1ee _exceptionPreprocess + 350
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x00007fff50864b20 objc_exception_throw + 48
2 Realm 0x000000010b69e11b ZN12_GLOBAL__N_114translateErrorIZ13RLMDynamicGetE3$5EEDaOT + 155
3 Realm 0x000000010b69dfdc RLMDynamicGet + 284
4 Realm 0x000000010b69e57d RLMDynamicGetByName + 1053
5 RealmSwift 0x000000010d6c2f44 $s10RealmSwift6ObjectCyypSgSScig + 708
6 RealmSwift 0x000000010d6c2b82 $s10RealmSwift6ObjectCyypSgSScigTo + 98
7 Realm 0x000000010b71ad1a -[RLMObjectBase descriptionWithMaxDepth:] + 714
8 Realm 0x000000010b6d4f7d RLMDescriptionWithMaxDepth + 1101
9 RealmSwift 0x000000010d6b4a27 $s10RealmSwift8ListBaseC23descriptionWithMaxDepth33_027551CC6B6B2DBBB6CF4A740CB6E5D6LLySSSuF + 247
10 RealmSwift 0x000000010d6b4bd0 $s10RealmSwift8ListBaseC23descriptionWithMaxDepth33_027551CC6B6B2DBBB6CF4A740CB6E5D6LLySSSuFTo + 48
11 Realm 0x000000010b71adc5 -[RLMObjectBase descriptionWithMaxDepth:] + 885
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not complaining about your object; its complaint about your `Realm`.  What does the code for `self.openRealm()` actually do and why is this an instance method?  Did you try replacing it with a regular `let realm = try? Realm()`. You can access a realm from another thread but you need to instantiate a Realm object for that thread; you cannot use the same Realm instance on thread that is different from he thread is was created on.  I would guess that you are creating and persisting the `Realm` on one thread then trying to use it here on another thread.

Comment: I think it was indeed complaining about the objects, the issue is you can create unmanaged objects but, their nested objects are not unmanaged